# How to do HTTPS STREAMING in android?

Tags: android, http

Hi i know that https streaming is not supported in android but i want to know is there any work around to stream a https content?

Comment: There may not be any libraries on the device, but if you code it from scratch (or port something) in a way consistent with the device's speed and compatible with the routing, bandwidth/reliability and usage rules of whatever network its on, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score -2):

[Http live streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming), used by iPhones/iPads is a particular http-based streaming protocol. It is supposed to be [available on Android 3.0](http://quitenoteworthy.blogspot.com/2011/03/http-live-streaming-and-android.html).

People have successfully used VLC to do rtp-streaming on Andropid: http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/d0hr0/howto_live_streaming_videoaudio_from_vlc_to_your/

VLC also supports http streaming, so maybe you should explore this further.

Comment: thank for the link but i want to know about https streaming ie secured streaming