# Why not all mp4 videos played on Android device?

Tags: android, video, mp4, playing

I tried to play the following two urls by video view on Android device, the first one has worked fine but the second one is not working. the second one may needs ssl certificate but i don't know how to play it the error code appears when I am trying to play it is :

```
 E/MediaPlayer error (1, -4)
```

I checked a link that mentioned list of error codes and it said that error(1,-4) means NotSupportedFormat. So why this error doesn't appear in the first link although both videos links are .mp4

The first working link :

```
 http://i250.photobucket.com/download-albums/gg264/APT08/APTAd3.mp4
```

The second not working link :

```
  http://*********/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4
  https://**********/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4
```

Note1: I asked a question related to this it helps to play the first link but the second still not working on android device

Note2: I am using the following code to play both links:

```
  VideoView myVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
         myVideo.setVideoPath("https://*********/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.mp4");
//       myVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://*************/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb0.mp4"));
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(myVideo);
    myVideo.setMediaController(mc);
    myVideo.requestFocus();
    mc.show();
```

Comment: Where did you saw the error list? Did you solve this ?? I am facing the same Problem ? Could tell What approach should solve this issue?

Comment: what is the url you are trying to test ?

Comment: i just tried the url that you given above

Comment: http://www.boisestatefootball.com/sites/default/files/videos/original/01%20-%20coach%20pete%20bio_4.mp4 i tried this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we dont have https playback support for android 3.0 -
only from 3.0 and above
 refer http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: I am able to play mp4 video like in the first link but the second one contains ssl certificate ... what shall I do to enable playing the video

Comment: you cant play HTTPS stream in android 3.1 and below pls refer the above link

Comment: I just tried to run it on device with Android updated version 4.0.4 but  it doesn't work

Comment: ofcourse now its secured that means encrypted you will have to decrypt to support that

Comment: Do you know how can I do it ? I tried some solution for avoiding ssl but it never worked for me

Comment: i dont feel i can --try saving and playing--
 refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017832/how-to-do-https-streaming-in-android

Comment: only MPEG @ TS is suported for live straming with HTTPS

Comment: thank you for your response, Actually I tried downloading then playing and it just worked fine, but I don;t want this behaviour

Comment: you will have to code from the scratch to implement live streaming try using NDK if you find any c or c++ code that might help